# How to validate Contact Form 7 Submit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form

I'm trying to send events to GA when a form is submitted, but while testing it, I've found that the wpcf7submit will send an event even if some required fields weren't fulfilled.

"wpcf7submit — Fires when an Ajax form submission has completed successfully, regardless of other incidents."

I've tested it with alerts and whenever I don't fill all the required fields I still get the alert

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    alert( "Fire!" );
}, false );
```

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector('.wpcf7');

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function (event) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Lead Form', 'submit');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the `wpcf7mailsent` event if you're only interested in successes.

```js
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector('.wpcf7');

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Lead Form', 'submit');
}, false);
```

> **wpcf7mailsent** — Fires when an Ajax form submission has completed successfully, and mail has been sent.

Comment: Note, this doesn't work with the skip mail setting enabled.